# CSS word-wrap on resizable divs

Tags: css, word-wrap

I am trying to use the CSS property `word-wrap` with the value `break-word` in a div.

It works perfectly, but only if I specify the width (and if this one values auto, word-wrap does not work).

The problem is that I want the div to be resizable, so I can't type a specific width for the div at the beginning.

Any ideas to solve this, please? I do not want to use hyphens.

Thank you in advance.

This does not work:

```
<p style="word-wrap: break-word !important;">loooooooooong_word</p>
```

This works OK:

```
<p style="width:100px; word-wrap: break-word !important;">loooooooooong_word</p>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg2Ff/)**

Comment: can you post some relevant html code?

Comment: Can you put your code in a fiddle or something?

Comment: word-wrap you need the word to be broken right??

Comment: Yes, I can't use word-break: break-all; if you mean that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `width:inherit` or `width:100%`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried both of them with same result :(

Answer (score 0):

In order for text in a div to wrap you have to specify the `white-space` CSS property for that div.

Set it to pre-wrap or normal.

eg. [Text Wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_white-space)

Also you can specify the `text-align:justify` property if you want the text to appear to be as in newspaper columns.

eg. [Justify](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_text-align&preval=justify)

Comment: Thak you for your help, I tried white-space with normal, initial, pre-wrap and pre-line, but nothing happened.

Comment: Why don't you specify the width in percentages or may be max-width and min width instead of just width, that will make the div resizable and the word will break when the div becomes too small.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>loooooooooooong_word</p>


<p style="word-wrap: break-word !important;">loooooooooong_word</p>

<p style="width: 100px; word-wrap: break-word !important;">loooooooooong_word</p>
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg2Ff/2/)**

Try resizing the browser the word wrap works fine...!! you can find the difference between the `<p>` tad without and with sytle and with fixed pixel

To be more clear the computer is dumb and if you want to break a word you should be specifying the condition at which the word should be broken. without giving the condition how you expect the output?

Comment: Yes, in Fiddle works fine; but not in my application. In fact, when I resize the browser, my looooooooooong_word just disappears!

Comment: can you show us where you have wrapped in the code,so the mistake may be in other css..

Comment: You are right, now I am trying my code out of the rest of the CSS classes and it works... The problem is that I am using a template made by other person. But I don't understand why !important is doing nothing.

Comment: happy that you found it..!! Cheers..!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [overflow-wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow-wrap/) property to get the word to break.

Further, you could set a limit on resizing by applying a `min-width`/`min-height` to the parent container.

Using your example, this is what I mean:

```html
<div style="resize: both; overflow: hidden; min-height: 100px; min-width: 100px; border: 2px dashed black; padding: 5px;">

  <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">loooooooooooong_word</p>
  <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">loooooooooooong_word</p>

</div>
```